# Uninstalling Voice Commands was apparently a terrible idea?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, voice-command, titanium-backup, force-close, motorola-flipside

In my efforts to free up space on my crappy Motorola Flipside, I thought that uninstalling Voice Commands would be a great idea since I never use it...

[image: error message]

Now after uninstalling it with Titanium, this message is an endless loop of forced closing. What are my options here?

Not sure if it would help. but here's a sample of the log when closing the error message:

```
12-07 11:49:43.030: I/Process(14069): Sending signal. PID: 14069 SIG: 9
12-07 11:49:43.061: W/InputManagerService(1298): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@47511bc8
12-07 11:49:43.084: I/ActivityManager(1298): Process com.nuance.android.vsuite.vsuiteapp (pid 14069) has died.
12-07 11:49:43.084: W/ActivityManager(1298): Unable to retrieve gids
12-07 11:49:43.084: W/ActivityManager(1298): android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.nuance.android.vsuite.vsuiteapp
12-07 11:49:43.084: W/ActivityManager(1298):    at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageGids(ContextImpl.java:1816)
12-07 11:49:43.084: W/ActivityManager(1298):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startProcessLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:2246)
12-07 11:49:43.084: W/ActivityManager(1298):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.cleanUpApplicationRecordLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:11210)
12-07 11:49:43.084: W/ActivityManager(1298):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleAppDiedLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:4902)
12-07 11:49:43.084: W/ActivityManager(1298):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.appDiedLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:5035)
12-07 11:49:43.084: W/ActivityManager(1298):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.access$000(ActivityManagerService.java:168)
12-07 11:49:43.084: W/ActivityManager(1298):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$AppDeathRecipient.binderDied(ActivityManagerService.java:1061)
12-07 11:49:43.084: W/ActivityManager(1298):    at android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice(Binder.java:362)
12-07 11:49:43.084: W/ActivityManager(1298):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
12-07 11:49:43.108: I/ActivityManager(1298): Start proc com.nuance.android.vsuite.vsuiteapp for restart com.nuance.android.vsuite.vsuiteapp: pid=14076 uid=10093 gids={}
12-07 11:49:43.225: W/asset(14076): Asset path /system/app/VSuiteApp.apk is neither a directory nor file (type=1).
12-07 11:49:43.233: D/AndroidRuntime(14076): Shutting down VM
12-07 11:49:43.233: W/dalvikvm(14076): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40020970)
12-07 11:49:43.241: E/AndroidRuntime(14076): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-07 11:49:43.241: E/AndroidRuntime(14076): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.nuance.android.vsuite.mot_vs32_cmb103.VSuiteApplicationMotVs32Cmb103: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.nuance.android.vsuite.mot_vs32_cmb103.VSuiteApplicationMotVs32Cmb103 in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/system/app/VSuiteApp.apk]
12-07 11:49:43.241: E/AndroidRuntime(14076):    at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo.makeApplication(ActivityThread.java:671)
12-07 11:49:43.241: E/AndroidRuntime(14076):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4322)
12-07 11:49:43.241: E/AndroidRuntime(14076):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3200(ActivityThread.java:129)
12-07 11:49:43.241: E/AndroidRuntime(14076):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2155)
12-07 11:49:43.241: E/AndroidRuntime(14076):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-07 11:49:43.241: E/AndroidRuntime(14076):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
12-07 11:49:43.241: E/AndroidRuntime(14076):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4717)
12-07 11:49:43.241: E/AndroidRuntime(14076):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-07 11:49:43.241: E/AndroidRuntime(14076):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-07 11:49:43.241: E/AndroidRuntime(14076):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
12-07 11:49:43.241: E/AndroidRuntime(14076):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
12-07 11:49:43.241: E/AndroidRuntime(14076):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-07 11:49:43.241: E/AndroidRuntime(14076): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.nuance.android.vsuite.mot_vs32_cmb103.VSuiteApplicationMotVs32Cmb103 in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/system/app/VSuiteApp.apk]
12-07 11:49:43.241: E/AndroidRuntime(14076):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
12-07 11:49:43.241: E/AndroidRuntime(14076):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
12-07 11:49:43.241: E/AndroidRuntime(14076):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
12-07 11:49:43.241: E/AndroidRuntime(14076):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:942)
12-07 11:49:43.241: E/AndroidRuntime(14076):    at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo.makeApplication(ActivityThread.java:666)
12-07 11:49:43.241: E/AndroidRuntime(14076):    ... 11 more
12-07 11:49:43.249: W/asset(1298): Asset path /system/app/VSuiteApp.apk is neither a directory nor file (type=1).
12-07 11:49:43.249: W/PackageManager(1298): Failure retrieving resources forcom.nuance.android.vsuite.vsuiteapp
12-07 11:49:43.249: W/asset(1298): Asset path /system/app/VSuiteApp.apk is neither a directory nor file (type=1).
12-07 11:49:43.249: W/PackageManager(1298): Failure retrieving resources forcom.nuance.android.vsuite.vsuiteapp
12-07 11:49:43.249: W/ActivityManager(1298): Process com.nuance.android.vsuite.vsuiteapp has crashed too many times: killing!
12-07 11:49:43.342: W/DropBoxManagerService(1298): Dropping: system_app_crash (1829 > 0 bytes)
12-07 11:49:44.936: D/RadioSignalLevel(1298): raw_sig_level = -97  iconLevel = 3
12-07 11:49:44.936: D/RadioSignalLevel(1298): Gsm Radio Signal level: 3
12-07 11:49:46.256: D/BatteryTempPolicy(1298): updateBatteryTemp temperature = 310, Threshhold = 3
12-07 11:49:46.264: D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(1298): received broadcast android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
12-07 11:49:46.264: D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(1298): new BatteryArgs: 2,90,2
12-07 11:49:46.264: D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(1298): handleBatteryUpdate
12-07 11:49:46.272: E/GlobalUnplugService(13488): plugged = true,mBatteryPlugged=true
12-07 11:49:46.295: E/Tethering(1298): active iface (usb1) reported as added, ignoring
12-07 11:49:46.303: D/StatusBarPolicy(1298): handleBatteryUpdate
12-07 11:49:46.303: D/WifiService(1298): ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED pluggedType: 2
```

Comment: Did you try removing VSuite as well?

Comment: @MatthewRead no, and I don't see it in the list of items in Titanium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically your options are to find a ROM to flash for that device and flash it. Or find the apk that you removed and re-add it.

You will probably need either a custom recovery, like ClockworkMod, or you may be able to put the apk back on the device using ADB from the android SDK.

I am not sure what the Custom ROM state is for this device, so it may be easier to find the apk that you need. If you can't find the apk, but can find a custom ROM, you could pull the apk from the ROM package.

Comment: I backed it up and froze it with Titanium before uninstalling, so hopefully the apk is on my SD card. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, the phone restated on its own before I was able to do anything and now I'm no longer seeing the message. I'll keep this in mind if I run into it again though, thanks again.

Comment: It is giving an FC because there is a running service/app which requires this app that you removed. A reboot should fix the FC, though it might reappear if you start the related ones.

Answer (score 1):

Two things in advance for future actions:

1. **always make a backup first** before fiddling around with system stuff (doesn't hurt in other cases either). <sup>As you did this, you can simply restore this (and don't need to read the following stuff -- which I still include for future readers with a similar problem)</sup>
2. before you go ahead and uninstall a system app, check for dependencies. You can do so by **first *freezing* the app** (which makes in unavailable, but is easily revertible by un-freezing -- *Titanium Backup* includes this feature as well) <sup>You did this, too -- so you should have noticed before. As you removed/uninstalled the app afterwards, the "frozen yog... ahem, stuff" is no longer available</sup>

**Now to the current situation:**

- As you made a backup with TB, you can simply restore it. If the described "endless loop" doesn't permit you to do so: There are some tools available permitting this from the recovery console (check e.g. XDA for [AROMA](http://www.xda-developers.com/android/manage-your-files-from-recovery-with-aroma-file-manager/), which simply can be flashed from recovery and then is available from there)
- If you still have the `image.zip` from your current ROM, you can simply extract it to an empty folder, go to the `system/apps` subfolder, pick the corresponding `.apk`, and side-load it to your device.
- If you have a second similar device running the same ROM (maybe a friends device), you can use *Titanium Backup* to make a transportable backup (`.tbk`) of the app (for most apps, in this special case better exclude its data), and use TB to restore this `.tbk` to your "broken device"